# Commands in Javascript code are overwritten by the last one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have stacked with my javascript code. In my app I am also using jQuery for faster writing some of the parts.

The thing is that after adding functionality to input files only the one added to the last is working. I found that maybe the reason is this same name of function with this same parameters. So to be sure I added to one my function which I want to use and to the other (I mean the first one) alert with simple text.

This is my code:

```
newRow.innerHTML = "<a href='#' class='editName'>"+ddList.ddElements[ddList.ddEl.id]+'</a>';
    newRow.innerHTML += ' X:<input type="text" id="x'+ddList.ddEl.id+'" name="x'+ddList.ddEl.id+'" size=3 value=0>';
    var xField = document.getElementById('x'+ddList.ddEl.id);
    xField.relatedElement = newRow;
    newRow.innerHTML += ' Y:<input type="text" id="y'+ddList.ddEl.id+'" name="y'+ddList.ddEl.id+'" size=3 value=0>';
    var yField = document.getElementById('y'+ddList.ddEl.id);
    yField.relatedElement = newRow;
    $(xField).blur(function(){alert('Handler for X.blur() called.')});
    $(yField).blur(function(){ddList.setObjectPosition(yField,obj,'y');});
    if(RegExprText.test(ddList.ddEl.id))
    {
        newRow.innerHTML += '<br>Kolor:';
        var element = document.createElement('input');
        element.setAttribute('id', 'c'+ddList.ddEl.id);
        element.setAttribute('name', 'c'+ddList.ddEl.id);
        element.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        element.setAttribute('class', 'color');
        element.setAttribute('size', '6');
        newRow.appendChild(element);
        var myPicker = new jscolor.color(element, {});
        $(element).blur(function(){ddList.setColor(element,obj);});
    }
    var links = newRow.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var editLink = links[links.length-1];
    editLink.relatedElement = newRow;
    $(editLink).click(function(){ddList.deleteObject(obj,newRow);});
```

So when I have got only X and Y input fields then only Y is active. When I have got X, Y and colorPicker then only colorPicker works.

Interesting thing is that always is working last line of code - editLink.

And I have been trying to change

`xField.relatedElement = newRow;`
on 
`newRow.addChild(xField);`

It doesn't work either.

Thanks for answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you do

```
xField.relatedElement = newRow;
```

And then you change

```
newRow.innerHTML
```

which will of course be reflected in the relatedElement.

If you want three different DOM elements, you have to make three different DOM elements, and not just one that you assign to three places and whose content you change three times.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I've got one more question. How I can define xField now, because I can't use `var xField = document.getElementById('x'+ddList.ddEl.id);` simply I haven`t got this element?